# How can I iterate through table styles only?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a procedure that iterates through the styles available to a document:

```
Sub EnumerateStyles()
  For Each Style in ActiveDocument.Styles
    `some custom code`
  Next
End Sub
```

I do not need all the styles, and just those that are applicable to tables only. How can I programmatically filter the styles?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh, finally figured out:

Style has the `Type` property, for the styles applicable to tables it is `wdStyleTypeTable`.